# HTML5 Localstorage access using Java

Tags: java, html, local-storage

Is it possible to access localstorage object using Java directly? If yes how?

Update: I am aware that localstorage is client side and java is server side but I read on net that GWT have api that allow to read localstorage.

Comment: You're talking about a Java applet?

Comment: For which scenario you are talking ?

Comment: I want to read localstorage from servlet filter, we are storing some Id in that.

Comment: @Dev G are you able to handle it. I also need to do same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The local storage, as its name indicates, stores information locally, which means in the browser, at client-side. The servlet filter executes at server-side. There is no way to access the local storage at server-side.

If you need to access some ID stored in the local storage from a servlet filter, then retrieve this ID from the local storage in JavaSCript, and send a request containing this ID to the server.

Comment: that is last option for me, but I was reading on net google GWT provides a API that allow to read the localstorage, what's that?

Comment: GWT allows writing applications in Java, that are compiled to JavaScript and executed in the browser. It doesn't have anything to do with servlet filters.

Comment: There is also the security requirement of localStorage not to share its data with any other system, including a development API (Java). The information is not sent from Client to Server.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is better alternative thamn Cookie. So, I am waiting JAVA support without external library for accessing local web storage, too. Now I am using sellenium support. Please, look at https://gist.github.com/dariodiaz/5079695

Comment: How can I use this local storage class to set and get the values, any example will helpful