# Is it a bad practice to have database calls in Filter classes?

Tags: java, session, servlet-filters

We have a web application. We want to prevent multiple login of same users. Basically, what we want to happen is this:

1. John logs in as "user1" in the application.
2. John's machine hangs a bit due to some unknown reason.
3. John cant wait. John goes to machine2, opens a browser there and logs in as "user1".
4. John's session in the browser in the first machine should now be invalidated.

to do this, we are planning to save in the database all sessionIds of all logged in users. This is to check if another user of the same username has logged-in in another machine or used another browser in the same machine. In order to implement this, we are planning to do a session id check in the Filter class that checks the session. With this there will be database calls every time the Filter class is invoked.

Is this a good practice?

EDIT:

The sessionId of the most recent user that has logged in will always be followed. So in the example, when John logs in using a browser in machine 2, the sessionId saved in the database (from machine1) will be overridden with the sessionId of the session in the browser in machine2. Now when the browser in machine1 is used again, it would automatically invalidate the session because it detects the sessionId for the user is now different

Comment: *John's session in the browser in the first machine should now be invalidated.* How can you be sure you won't invalidate John's second machine?

Comment: Do you want sessions to be persistent? If not I don't see any need to store the sessionIds in the database. Just keep them in memory and check there. If the application is clustered you might have to take some more action but it should still be doable this way.

Comment: You can use local storage to store the sessionId and if he uses second browser then you can add a check, whether sessionId is present or not

Comment: @Thomas: you mean use singletons? but we shouldn't make static classes mutable right?

Comment: @Rohan Kawade: you mean like use a file?

Comment: It wouldn't be exactly a singleton. It would be more like a cache, application scoped CDI bean etc. - the instance itself wouldn't be static.

Comment: @Davoin Showerhandles: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217423/html5-localstorage-access-using-java

Comment: if you HAVE to hit a db inside a filter, you can only make the call as optimized as possible. spring-security evaluates the user against a db inside its filters, so it's nothing wrong with this approach

Comment: @Thomas: so could I also use some third party cache for it like EhCache?

Comment: @injecteer: really? i didnt know that about spring security

Comment: Yeah EhCache etc. should work.

Comment: @DavoinShowerhandles, well the `springSecurityFilterChain` is defined in `web.xml` as a `filter`, so yes it does. My conclusion: don't over-develop or prematurely optimize your app. If it feels right to do something somewhere - do it, if there are no real limitations to be concerned of. What you really should not do is access the db inside a JSP-page, the rest is up to you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you call a database call. It is perfectly acceptable that a filter uses a value from the database. But directly having database calls in a filter is indeed a  bad practice because it does not respect layered development.

My advice is that a filter should only call the service layer.

A comment gave the example of Spring Security, where the user-role database is used in the filter machinery. But in fact, the filter classes do not know anything of the database, and ask other classes (equivalent of service and persistence layer) to do the actual job.

TL/DR: **using** database stored data in a filter is ok, having JDBC calls in a filter should be avoided.